# Why was Jaskier's "Polish name" used and not Dandelion, the "English name"?

Tags: the-witcher

In the English translation of *The Witcher*, Geralt's friend, the bard, is called Dandelion. This caused me a brief bit of confusion when I started watching the series when his name was introduced as Jaskier instead.

Upon looking into the [fandom wiki](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/Dandelion) I see that Jaskier was his name in the original Polish version of the books. As far as I can tell most of the names and places in the series are the same as they were in the books. Though I don't know if anything other than Dandelion was changed between the Polish and English versions of the books.

Why was Jaskier used instead of Dandelion in the TV series?

Comment: https://www.thegamer.com/the-witcher-heres-why-dandelion-is-named-jaskier-in-the-show/

Comment: Possible dupe from SFF movie site here: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/105829/why-are-they-calling-him-jaskier

Comment: Because Dandelion is a silly name

Comment: @Valorum isn't Jaskier meant to sound silly in Polish? If so, Dandelion would be a good choice, even if Buttercup or whatever would have been better.

Comment: Because it's his name? Yeah, technically it's a nickname, but the real one is almost never used, it should not be pseudotranslated in first place.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From looking around I have seen that Lauren S. Hissrich, the show runner, has given two reasons why she went with Jaskier over Dandelion.

#### To match the author's intent

She has mentioned on Twitter back in June 2018 when initially questioned over it that is was to match the author's intent. It's quite fun reading the tweets and her replies to the reasons some people give for why they don't like it.

> **@LHissrich:** Geralt is Geralt in every translation. So is Yennefer. Jaskier is... all over the place. I’m taking him back to his roots, as the author intended.
>
> **@LHissrich:** Jaskier is the original name in the books. It was translated into English, later, as Dandelion.
>
> <sub>[Twitter, 7:49 am Jun 23, 2018](https://twitter.com/LHissrich/status/1010414431698743296)</sub>

For a bit of an aside Jaskier when translated from Polish into English actually means buttercup, the original translator felt that wasn't quite fitting for Jaskier's personality and so changed it to Dandelion. This is what Lauren is referring to above.

> **@Smashycomman:** In the books: Dandelion. In the games: Dandelion. In the comics: Dandelion. In the Polish novels: Jaskier. Are you producing this show in Polish? No? THEN WHY WOULD YOU NAME HIM JASKIER?!?
>
> **@vonschirz:** Exactly. From my point of view iťs sad and nonsense. JASKIER has got no linguistic base nor meaning in English.
>
> **@LHissrich:** But... neither does Yennefer. It’s not an English name. Nor is Geralt.
>
> [...]
>
> **@LHissrich:** True. I get that. I guess in terms of adaptations go, I just always want to protect the author’s intent as much as I can, including the proper names he specifically chose.
>
> **@LHissrich:** For what it’s worth, I LOVE the name Jaskier. It does sound romantic and foppish and delightful to my ear.
>
> <sub>[Twitter, 7:17 am 23 Jun 2018](https://twitter.com/LHissrich/status/1010406468388962304)</sub>

She also gives an extra reason in the last tweet there, she loves the name Jaskier and presumably thinks it matches the character better than Dandelion.

#### The pronunciation issue

If the audiobooks are anything to go by Dandelion is not pronounced like the flower but rather "Dan-dill-ion". This appears to have been at least part of the reason to go back to the character's original name.

> "We call him Jaskier. Yeah, absolutely. Jaskier is 100% in the show," Hissrich said. "It's interesting, because people ask about Jaskier all the time and why we went with his original name. It is funny, part of it was because when I read the books I read it as Dandelion (the flower), and then I listened to the audiobooks. Dandelion (pronounced Dan-dill-ion), how would I get that?"
>
> <sub>[ComicBook, The Witcher Showrunner Confirms Unexpected Fan-Favorite Character Appears](https://comicbook.com/gaming/2019/07/23/netflix-the-witcher-showrunner-dandelion-is-in-show/)</sub>

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the last part, is "dan-dill-ion" not the way you pronunce the flower?  I suppose "dandy-lion" is also a common pronunciation, but dan-dih-lion / dan-dill-ion (which are hard to distinguish) are pretty normal to me...

Comment: @Joe it’s the last syllable that’s the odd one out, I’ve never heard it pronounced as -ion only -lion.

Comment: I expect that the first is /dændəlaɪən/ and the second is /dændɪliən/. They're pretty different.

Comment: Does  /dændɪliən/ rhyme with "million"?

Comment: IMO this has the exact opposite effect of "matching the author's intent". Jaskier is a silly name in Polish, but it just sounds like a fantasy name in English

Comment: @Joe I didn't listen to the audio books but I am guessing that the distinction is that the flower is pronounced something like "dan-dee-lie-on" and the name is pronounced as "dan-dill-ee-on" or perhaps "dan-dill-yuhn" (like Segfault suggested that it may rhyme with "million" which is pronounced as "mill-ee-on" or as "mill-yuhn")

Comment: @Max at least she's got consistency though. The other media took liberties with *his* name, but left the others intact, which does strike me as rather odd. Now each character has their own original name back.

Comment: The difference is stress: *dandelion* has the stress on the first syllable. /Dan-dill-ion/ has the stress on the second syllable (and is not supported by the spelling, i.e. I totally agree with the "how would I get that?" comment).

Comment: By the way, the German version calls Jaskier "Rittersporn" (Which means larkspur, but the literal translation of the flower's name would be "knight's spur"). Could be because the name "Löwenzahn" (the German name for dandelion) is already taken by [a German edutainment show for children which ran until 2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Löwenzahn) and they didn't want that association.

Comment: @Philipp:  "Löwenzahn" is still running.  Up until 2005, the main character was played by Peter Lustig.  A guy by the name of Guido Hammesfahr took over in 2006, and the show is still running.  I watch it most Sunday mornings while waiting for [The Mouse.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Sendung_mit_der_Maus)

Comment: @Max - Nickname or not, it's still what people call him. Just like how we talk about the cartel leaders El Chapo and El Mencho, instead of Shortie and...well, I honestly don't what his name means.